# Is this common practice for a read-only property that accesses the database

Tags: asp.net, caching, properties, readonly

If I have a read-only property on an object that fills itself via the DB, is this what I should be doing, or is there a better way to make sure it's already been evaluated?

```
private List<Variable> _selectedVariables;
public new List<Variable> SelectedVariables
{
    get
    {
        if (_selectedVariables == null)
        {
            _selectedVariables = SomeFunctionThatCallsDB();
        }
        return _selectedVariables;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most people call that lazy loading. It's pretty common.

Comment: This is the best article that I have read about the Singleton pattern in C# and thread safety: [C# in Depth: Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: @pickypg my class isn't a static class though. does that article still apply?

Comment: Not all of it. A lot deals with Singleton's in particular. The one that is probably most interesting to you is the [System.Lazy Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx). That's number 6 from the previous link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine for a single thread; but you will have problems if that is going to be in a situation where you have multithreaded gets.

EDIT: Threadsafing:

Simple Threadsafe pattern:

```
private readonly object _objectLock = new object();
private List<T> _someList = null;

public List<T> MyStuff
{
    get
    {
         if(_someList == null)
         {
             lock(_objectLock)
             {
                  if(_someList == null)
                     _someList = LoadFromDB();
             }
         }

         return _someList;
    }
}
```

You check to see if set, then lock, then check again to make sure you covered the race condition.

Comment: @Jason, Added Edit to provide a sample.

Comment: @glowcoder, I'm not sure I understand. The check is both outside and inside the lock.